# Detect all extensions in browser (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser, navigator

I need to detect all extensions installed in the browser, like adblock or User-Agent switcher.

```
navigator.plugins
```

returns a list of all plugins, do we have something similar to detect all extensions installed  (through Javascript?) ?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Plugins are designed for webpages to use.

Extensions are designed to use webpages.

A specific extension might inject something into a page that you can detect, but there is nothing generic.

Comment: Thanks. Oddly, i could not find any documentation supporting the same fact that extensions can not be detected, could you point me to one ?

Comment: I doubt that there is any documentation for a feature that does not exist. Since it doesn't exist, there is nothing to document.

Comment: if there is no such feature, i suppose there would be a reason ? Since we can display all plugins why behave differently with extensions ?

Comment: It is no business of any web site author to know what extensions I use in my browser … you might have heard of a thing called “privacy” …

Comment: If someone had sat down and considered if they should build the feature into the browser they were writing and decided not to, then they *might* document that decision. If someone never thought about building the feature because they had no reason to build it then they would not document it.